# How to remove item in String Array?

Tags: ios, json, string, swift, dictionary

I have a JSON String like this:

```
let stringArray = "[{\"url\":\"www.abc.com\",\"name\":\"benson\",\"age\":25},{\"url\":\"www.abc.com\",\"name\":\"tommy\",\"age\":23}]"
```

How can I remove one item(for example,tommy) in this string?

I tried to cast it to `[[NSObject: AnyObject]]` but always failed.

```
if let dictArray = stringArray as? [[NSObject: AnyObject]] {


} else {

    println("failed") // print failed.
}
```

How can I get the result like this:

```
[{\"url\":\"www.abc.com\",\"name\":\"benson\",\"age\":25}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert your string to array because its JSON String

```
    var stringArray = "[{\"url\":\"www.abc.com\",\"name\":\"benson\",\"age\":25},{\"url\":\"www.abc.com\",\"name\":\"tommy\",\"age\":23}]"

    var data : NSData = stringArray.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)!
    var error: NSError?
    var array = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.allZeros, error: &error) as Array<AnyObject>
    println(array)
```

Output :

```
[{
    age = 25;
    name = benson;
    url = "www.abc.com";
}, {
    age = 23;
    name = tommy;
    url = "www.abc.com";
}]
```

Now perform delete operation

```
    array.removeAtIndex(1)
    println(array)
```

Output :

```
[{
    age = 25;
    name = benson;
    url = "www.abc.com";
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

First convert your json string to swift array or dictionary;

```
   let stringArray:String = "[{\"url\":\"www.abc.com\",\"name\":\"benson\",\"age\":25},{\"url\":\"www.abc.com\",\"name\":\"tommy\",\"age\":23}]"

    let data:NSData = stringArray.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)!;

    let dict:NSArray = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: nil, error: nil) as! NSArray;

    NSLog("dict \(dict)");
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can cast the original jsons string to the dictionary then pick up the keys what your needs. as the sample code like :

```
    if let json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData("your string to NSDATA",options:NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments,$error){
   // checks the son type and make sure the operation perform to the NSDictionary
   var d = json as! NSDictionary;
   // Picks the the values your want from d
}
```